# How are Highcharts event listeners handled

Tags: javascript, highcharts, react-highcharts

I have a react app which shows some chart visualizations using highcharts library. There are some custom extensions used on top of Highcharts implementation. Highcharts are created using `Highcharts.chart()` method. I also see tooltips applied to these charts. My question is how are these event listeners handled. Where is the JS file stored to handle these mouse events on the web page? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Events assignments you can found in `Pointer.prototype.setDOMEvents`.

For the chart click, the input is in `container.onclick = this.onContainerClick.bind(this);`

From debugger at this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/eg57sjuL/1/) you can go all the way up to the event, which is `onContainerClick`.

Global event (window) is hooked up to resize `chart.reflow` - you can view it in the console under `call stack list`, is there under the name `Global Listeners`.